# Generic class references

Tags: java

Please look into following code. Why this error is thrown even though Integer is inherited from Number and why the same case of error is not there when '? extends Number' is used.

```
public class testGeneric
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
          Class<Integer> classint = int.class;
          Class<Number> classnum1 = int.class;// Error Type mismatch: cannot convert from  
                                              // Class<Integer> to Class<Number>
          Class<? extends Number> classnum2 = int.class;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Hi.That was an typo. I have corrected it. Please take a look again

Answer (score 1):

You do not have co-variance (if that is the word I am looking for) in generic types.

They need to match exactly.

`Class<Number>` can only be assigned by `Number.class`.

If you want to allow subclassed (or superclasses) you have to use `extends` or `super`.

`Class<? extends Number>` can take `Integer.class` (among others, such as  `Long.class` or `Number.class`).

`Class<? super Number>` can take `Number.class` or `Object.class`.

---

This is different from methods of a generic type being able to work on subclass instances.

For example, you can add an `Integer` into a `List<Number>`, but that does not make `List<Number>` assignable to `List<Integer>` (or vice versa).

---

An object instance can be used where a superclass is required, but a generic type cannot.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding

`Autoboxing and Unboxing` is happening for Integer and int, but it is not possible for Number and int.

For info about autoboxing refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: My question is why there is error even though Integer is sub of Number, and even if the type mismatch is thrown up for some reason than why the code works perfect with extends keyword.

Comment: This does not have to do with auto boxing and unboxing.